# how to make progress bar

Tags: java, android, eclipse

i have two activities in one activities I do stopword removal process and show in activities two, This process takes a long time if the amount of words more and more, I want to make a progress bar so that users are not confused.
how to make a progress bar until stopword removal process is complete?
and I had to put it where the coding?
I am a beginner in android programming, I hope anyone can help me.

this is my coding on click button at activities one.

```
public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    if (v.getId()==R.id.button6){
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, PreposisiRemoval.class);

        String test = ((TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView7)).getText().toString();
        String[] preposisi = {"akibat", "atas", "bagai", "bagi", "berkat", "dalam", "dari", "demi", "dengan", "di", "hingga", "karena", "ke", "kecuali", "lewat", "oleh", "pada", "sampai", "sejak", "seperti", "tanpa", "tentang", "untuk"};
        StringBuilder resultFilter = new StringBuilder();

        Scanner fip1 = new Scanner(test);
            while (fip1.hasNext()){
                    int flag = 1;
                    String s1 = fip1.next();
                    for (int i = 0;i<preposisi.length; i++){
                        if (s1.equals(preposisi[i])){
                            flag=0;
                        }
                        }   
                        if(flag!=0){
                            System.out.println(s1);
                            resultFilter.append(s1+'\n');
                        }

                        Intent intent2 = getIntent();
                                String count = intent2.getStringExtra("result2");

                    intent.putExtra("resultFilter", resultFilter.toString());
                    intent.putExtra("count", count);
                    startActivity(intent);
                    }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do such things with AsyncTask or just putting the ProgressDialog.show() before your work start and dismiss when complete.for asyncTask ,code is as follows.

```
 private class doLoginTask extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, String>{

    private ProgressDialog pb=null;
    //private String response=null;
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPreExecute();
                    //Progress show
        pb=ProgressDialog.show(ClubLoginActivity.this, "", "Processing");
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        //add your work here..

        return myWork();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        pb.dismiss();
                    //code after dismiss it.
                    Intent intent2 = getIntent();
    String count = intent2.getStringExtra("result2");
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, PreposisiRemoval.class);

    intent.putExtra("resultFilter", resultFilter.toString());
    intent.putExtra("count", result);
    startActivity(intent);

    }
}
    String myWork(){

    String test = ((TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView7)).getText().toString();
    String[] preposisi = {"akibat", "atas", "bagai", "bagi", "berkat", "dalam", "dari", "demi", "dengan", "di", "hingga", "karena", "ke", "kecuali", "lewat", "oleh", "pada", "sampai", "sejak", "seperti", "tanpa", "tentang", "untuk"};
    StringBuilder resultFilter = new StringBuilder();

    Scanner fip1 = new Scanner(test);
        while (fip1.hasNext()){
                int flag = 1;
                String s1 = fip1.next();
                for (int i = 0;i<preposisi.length; i++){
                    if (s1.equals(preposisi[i])){
                        flag=0;
                    }
                    }   
                    if(flag!=0){
                        System.out.println(s1);
                        resultFilter.append(s1+'\n');
                    }


}
        return resultFilter.toString();
}
```

Comment: where i put this code? activity 1? 
could you please implement with my coding above?

Comment: sir can i get you email address, i want question something about this.

Answer (score 0):

try this code

```
   public void onClick(View v) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
if (v.getId()==R.id.button6){
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, PreposisiRemoval.class);

    String test = ((TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView7)).getText().toString();
    String[] preposisi = {"akibat", "atas", "bagai", "bagi", "berkat", "dalam", "dari", "demi", "dengan", "di", "hingga", "karena", "ke", "kecuali", "lewat", "oleh", "pada", "sampai", "sejak", "seperti", "tanpa", "tentang", "untuk"};
    StringBuilder resultFilter = new StringBuilder();

    Scanner fip1 = new Scanner(test);
    ProgressDialog dialog = ProgressDialog.show(MainActivity.this,"Wait Dialog","Please wait...", true, false);
        while (fip1.hasNext()){
                int flag = 1;
                String s1 = fip1.next();
                for (int i = 0;i<preposisi.length; i++){
                    if (s1.equals(preposisi[i])){
                        flag=0;
                    }
                    }   
                    if(flag!=0){
                        System.out.println(s1);
                        resultFilter.append(s1+'\n');
                    }
                  dialog.cancel();
                    Intent intent2 = getIntent();
                            String count = intent2.getStringExtra("result2");

                intent.putExtra("resultFilter", resultFilter.toString());
                intent.putExtra("count", count);
                startActivity(intent);
                }
        }
    }
```